# Nginx Mutual Auth for consuming Rest API

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ca

I want to secure a collection of web APIs I'm writing. The access to those APIs must be granted to subscribers until the subscription expires; the APIs are consumed by remote web services. So I thought that Mutual SSL is the best 
 way to do that.

I'm trying to set up my own CA to issue x509 certificates to clients.

This is the first time I'm doing this; so, naturally, nothing works.

This is what I want to get as end-result: I deploy my APIs using Nginx as a reverse-proxy; if the client sends a valid certificate to Nginx, the reverse proxy accepts the connection and it forwards the requests; the connection is closed otherwise. Whenever a new client signs a subscription, I generate a new certificate and send it to him/her.

So I followed [this](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html) guide, that seemed to me to be more complete than others I read, and I put a self-signed `ca.crt` in `/etc/ssl/ca/cert` for signing the `CSR`s received from clients and I set up nginx as

```
server {
    listen *:443    ssl;
    server_name     api.example.com;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem; #certificate from an actual CA
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key; #PK of server.pem
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_crl /etc/ssl/ca/crl/ca.crl;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on; #ensure your cert is capable
    ssl_stapling_verify on; #ensure your cert is capable
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    #Redirects all traffic
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysecuredserver/api$request_uri;
        limit_req       zone=one burst=10;
    }
}
```

But when I consume a `Test` api (it always responds with a `200 OK`) using

```
curl -k -v --key key.pem --cert cert.pem https://api.example.com/Test
```

I always get the following error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 18:00:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 224
< Connection: close
< 
<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Could anybody explain to me what's wrong?

Second question: in `ssl_certificate` I put the cert I bought from a valid CA: is that right or should I put a cert generated using the `ca.crt` instead?

Comment: Take baby steps. You want to take this one step at a time. `Step 1. Your SSL certificate works`. So remove `ssl_verify_client on; ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/ca.crt;`. See if you connect fine using `curl -v https://api.example.com/Test`. Step 2 - Add client certificate and make verify optional. Add `ssl_verify_client optional;ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/ca.crt;`. In `location /` add `return 200 "Client cert status -  $ssl_client_verify". This will tell you if server was able to verify cert or not

Comment: Step 1: works fine. Step 2 with `ssl_verify_client optional`: 400 Bad Request, same message

Comment: Change `ssl_verify_client off` and then try and also what does the nginx log say?

Comment: It connects: I attach the curl output
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 19:53:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 25
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.proximity-marketing.it left intact
Client cert status - NONE

Comment: /var/log/nginx/error.log says nothing at all
2017/09/29 19:52:43 [notice] 28279#0: signal process started
2017/09/29 19:53:53 [notice] 28300#0: signal process started
2017/09/29 19:54:29 [notice] 28312#0: signal process started

Comment: `ssl_verify_client optional;`, when the 400 came what was the error log showing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155629/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-gogolander).

Comment: You could also try `ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca`, and separately, use the openssl command line to verify that the cert.pem is verified correctly by ca.crt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed when you don't get much logs in Nginx you should add

```
debug_connection <IP>;
```

It will generate more logs. Which showed

```
2017/09/29 20:27:55 [info] 28783#0: *72 client SSL certificate verify error: (3:unable to get certificate CRL) while reading client request headers
```

This error occurs when you don't provide CRL for every certificate in the `ssl_client_certificate` chain.

Below are similar thread showing the same issue

https://serverfault.com/questions/501912/nginx-proxy-ssl-clr-400-bad-request-error

[Nginx unable to get certificate CRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086934/nginx-unable-to-get-certificate-crl)

You need to specify the directive `ssl_crl` and give it the CRL file

```
  ssl_crl /etc/ssl/certs/crl/ca.crl;
```

Additionally, you should verify that `ssl_certificate` refers to the certificate created by your CA for your server:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/server.pem;       #signed by your CA

ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ca/private/server.key; #PK used to generate 
                                                    #server.pem

ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca/certs/ca.crt;

ssl_crl /etc/ssl/ca/crl/ca.crl;                     #CRL of the
                                                    #ssl_client_certificate and
                                                    #its chain
```